# How to set notifications in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Please tell  me before mango release how to set the notifications in windows phone 7?

Comment: http://www.thisisfanzoo.com/Blog/JeffF/archive/2010/08/02/a-really-long-post-about-the-windows-phone-7-push.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=wp7+push+notifications